# Cisco Licence expired

Tags: cisco

If you need to use a certain feature on a Cisco router, you need to enable to the licence, fair enough.

However, i have witnessed licences expire, and nothing happens???

Before ....

`Index 2 Feature: securityk9

    Period left: 1  day  18 hours 
    Period Used: 8  weeks 2  days 
    License Type: EvalRightToUse
    License State: Active, In Use
    License Count: Non-Counted
    License Priority: Low`

After ...

`Index 2 Feature: securityk9

        Period left: Life time
        License Type: RightToUse
        License State: Active, In Use
        License Count: Non-Counted
        License Priority: Low`

So now i have a 'RightToUse' licence, i am led to believe that this honor based, i.e. use it until you pay for it ????

I was informed that after a reboot 'securityk9' will not work, but that turned out not to be true, its just the same after the reboot.

But that does not make sense, i thought Cisco were clamping down on this, to add to their billlions....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless something has changed very recently with Cisco's licensing model, the expiration of the eval license does not cause the featureset to stop working on the appliance.  But the EULA you had to accept before enabling the RTU license says something to the effect that you won't try to use it past the 90-day mark.

Answer (score 2):

From [Software Activation on Cisco Integrated Services Routers and Cisco Integrated Service Routers G2](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/routers/access/sw_activation/SA_on_ISR.pdf)

> Starting with Cisco IOS Releases 15.0(1)M6, 15.1(1)T4, 15.1(2)T4, 15.1(3)T2, and 15.1(4)M, Evaluation licenses are replaced with Evaluation Right To Use licenses. **Evaluation Right to Use licenses automatically become Right to Use licenses after the initial evaluation period.**
>
> When you order a license from Cisco, you will receive a Right to Use Notification. You may begin using the licensed features upon receipt of the Right to Use Notification. Keep the Right to Use Notification for your records as proof of your license purchase.
>   Right to Use licenses are available on Cisco IOS Release 15.0(1)M4, 15.1(1)T2, 15.1(2)T2, 15.1(3)T, 15.1(4)M1, or later. 
>   **These licenses are available on the honor system**

Answer (score 0):

Cisco hardware ready to use on buy but some software features need license to work actively like mpls traffic engineering or Brodging L3 to L2 vpn access solutions.